# Sublime Text 3 its not using default python

Tags: python, ide, sublimetext3, canopy, sublimerepl

I recently installed sublime text 3 in my pc (Ubuntu 13.10). And i also installed Canopy Enthought and set canopy as default python. But Sublime text instead of using the new default python and ipython, its using the "old" version. In windows i used to run ipython console with SublimeREPL and i have no problems with Canopy. I verified in Terminal the following with this results:

```
    ~$ which python
    /home/ccp/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
    ~$ which ipython
    /home/ccp/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/ipython
```

So there's no problem with Canopy as default, in Terminal i can access to Canopy python 2.7.3 and also ipython with python 2.7.3 but in sublimeREPL opens python2.7.5+(Ubuntu "old" default).
There's some place where i can changed this? i tried reinstalling Sublime Text 3 but it didnt solve the problem.

TERMINAL:

```
    Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.3 | 64-bit | (default, Dec  2 2013, 16:23:35) 
    [GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>>
```

PYTHON (SUBLIMEREPL):

```
    Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
    [GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new file with the following contents:

```json
[
     {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "r",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {"caption": "Python",
                "id": "Python",

                 "children":[
                    {"command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python - Canopy",
                     "id": "repl_python",
                     "mnemonic": "p",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "cmd": ["/home/ccp/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python", "-i", "-u"],
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
                        }
                    },
                    {"command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python - IPython - Canopy",
                     "id": "repl_python_ipython",
                     "mnemonic": "p",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "autocomplete_server": true,
                        "cmd": ["/home/ccp/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python", "-u", "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {
                            "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8",
                            "SUBLIMEREPL_EDITOR": "$editor"
                        }
                    }
                    }
                ]}
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

and save it as `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu`. This will add `Python - Canopy` and `Python - IPython - Canopy` options to the `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Python` menu.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks that actually solved the problem! now im also capable of opening ipython-Canopy with ctrl+shift+i. If anyone whants this configuration my Key Bindings- User its below:

```
[{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+i"],                    
                     "command": "repl_open",
                     "caption": "Python - IPython - Canopy",
                     "id": "repl_python_ipython",
                     "mnemonic": "p",
                     "args": {
                        "type": "subprocess",
                        "encoding": "utf8",
                        "autocomplete_server": true,
                        "cmd": ["/home/ccp/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python", "-u",         "${packages}/SublimeREPL/config/Python/ipy_repl.py"],
                        "cwd": "$file_path",
                        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                        "external_id": "python",
                        "extend_env": {
                            "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8",
                            "SUBLIMEREPL_EDITOR": "$editor"
                        }
                    }},
{ "keys": ["ctrl+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": false } },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": { "block": true } },
]
```